SFMC - Contact who change busines unit
I'm an SFMC Expert and i'm facing a use case that I never encountered. I'm constructing a multiple business unit organization, and my contacts, dedicated to a business unit due to a business rules on their prefered store, can change business unit.
If a contact enter in a Journey, and change from a business unit to another during the journey, what's happening ?
The contact will still in the journey ?
The contact will be out of the journey ?
Thanks by advance for your feedback !
Regards,

Firstly: How do you define a relationship between a contact and a business unit?
Contacts are global to your environment (i.e. you can't delete them from a single BU), so once a contact is in your journey, it will continue until the end - unless actively removed e.g. using this API or appropriate exit criteria.
You could consider using Subscriber Filters, but these will only work for emails.

Thanks for your answer Lukas.
My relationship is base on a business rule. We receive all the WordlWide data into the parent business unit and we dispatch these data into the child BU depending the contact zone.
Regards,
